# Why does Consumed Filament vary between MAFX and G-code?

Tags: g-code, post-processing

I am attempting to set up an MMU, the Mosaic Palette 3 Pro, with my Ender 3 (original version), with mods of note being Klipper firmware and the MicroSwiss Direct Drive NG Extruder. Accessory Mode is the mode of operation and I have set the outgoing tube length and loading offset appropriately.

After some trial and error of the MMU not creating enough filament for the outgoing tube, I am dealing with (hopefully the last setup-related issue) prints running out of filament approximately 75% through on the test keychain.

I slice with PrusaSlicer, so I can have an offline slicer, and use P2PP for post-processing.

However, the file that I see on Klipper and the generated MAFX from PrusaSlicer+P2PP vary wildly in the amount of filament consumed.

Why is the Palette claiming that it only requires 1.99 meters of filament for the job, while Klipper thinks it's 2.45 meters from the uploaded G-code?

Current P2PP start G-code for PrusaSlicer:

````
BED_MESH_PROFILE LOAD="default";
G28;
M82;
G92 E0;


;P2PP PALETTE3_PRO
;P2PP P3_UPLOADFILE
;P2PP PRINTERPROFILE=12345678901234567890123456789012

;P2PP P3_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.8
;P2PP P3_SHOWPRINTERPAGE
;P2PP P3_PROCESSPREHEAT
;P2PP SPLICEOFFSET=40
;P2PP MINSTARTSPLICE=130
;P2PP MINSPLICE=90
;P2PP EXTRAENDFILAMENT=150
;P2PP LINEARPINGLENGTH=350
;P2PP MATERIAL_PLA_PLA_2_2_1
;P2PP MATERIAL_PLA_PVA_3_3_-4
;P2PP MATERIAL_PVA_PLA_3_3_-4
;P2PP KLIPPER_TOOLCHANGE
;P2PP ACCESSORYMODE_MAFX 
;P2PP ABSOLUTEEXTRUDER
;P2PP CONFIGEND
```
````